# Cannot import font-face in scss

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, fonts

I am attempting to import [google font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Luckiest+Guy) in my project.

This is what I expect:
[image]

Actual Result:
[image]

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">Luckiest Guy</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "./assets/scss/main.scss";

#app {
  font-family: "Luckiest Guy", "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

main.scss

```
@import '../fonts/fonts.scss';
```

fonts.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap');
}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-frost-2mbuf?file=/src/App.vue

**Update 1**

I also tried to use downloaded otf, but not working

fonts.scss

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
   src: url('<The relative path of the otf>');
}
```

**Update 2**

I also tried to use downloaded otf, but not working

@font-face {
font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
src: url('./LuckiestGuy-Regular.ttf');
}

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-frost-2mbuf?file=/src/assets/fonts/fonts.scss

Comment: Have you tried getting the other extensions of font face on there too ? .woff or .woff2.

Answer (score 0):

When importing fonts with google fonts you can use the import url or you can download the font. Currently you are importing css code which contains:

```
/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/luckiestguy/v11/_gP_1RrxsjcxVyin9l9n_j2hTd52.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Now you are using this code in your @font-face `src` property, there are 3 ways to fix this issue:

**Use the same url**

one option is to use the same URL google uses (https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/luckiestguy/v11/_gP_1RrxsjcxVyin9l9n_j2hTd52.woff2)

**Download locally**

an other option is to download the font locally and save it in your project, then use font-face to import it in your scss. You can download a font (on google fonts) by clicked the `download family` button in the top right corner (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Luckiest+Guy), then you can put these files anywhere in your project and instead of using `htts://...` in your `src` you will need to navigate to that folder

**Use google's import url**

the last and easiest option is to import css with the link:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap");
```

Comment: I forked the OP's sandbox and demonstrated what @Markiesch suggested. The font works for me.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-mccarthy-jjxce?file=/src/assets/fonts/fonts.scss

Comment: @Markiesch can you demonstrate how to Download locally. I tried to download and import it as font-face but not working. Please check my update above

Comment: @CCCC I edited the answer with the explenation there :)

Comment: @Markiesch Please check my update 2.